# Android draw the bitmap in specified X,Y positions in the canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

> I have two images , first image is having the transparent area in
>   that.the second image i have to fit the transparent area of the first
>   image . for that i have the first image height, width , x, y values.i
>   am combining those two images by drawing the bitmap on canvas like
>   below.

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(overLay.getWidth(),
            overLay.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas combineImg = new Canvas(bm);

    combineImg.drawBitmap(overLay, 0, 0, null);
    // combineImg.drawbitma
    combineImg.drawBitmap(mask, 61, 111, null);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    img.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

> but it is not fitting at correct position . any one have the idea please explain here.
>   the out put i am getting as below.
>   [image]

Comment: @pskink those are the x,y coordinates sent by server. with those x,y values in ios its fitting at correct position

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the x y position from the top edge...
And when you merge them, there's the error...
get the bitmap x y inside image view, subtract the error and then give those x y positions to merge the bitmaps.

```
    int ih = backgroundIv.getHeight();//height of imageView
    int iw = backgroundIv.getWidth();//width of imageView
    int iH = backgroundIv.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();//original height of underlying image
    int iW = backgroundIv.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();//original width of underlying image


    if (ih/iH<=iw/iW) iw=iW*ih/iH;//rescaled width of image within ImageView
    else ih= iH*iw/iW;//rescaled height of image within ImageView

    iv_OverlayImage.requestLayout();
    iv_OverlayImage.getLayoutParams().height = ih;
    iv_OverlayImage.getLayoutParams().width = iw;

    pixelsToRight = (backgroundIv.getWidth() - iw)/2;
```

I hope this helps...
Cheers :)